# JS lengthy computation: split it up with a good syntax?

Tags: javascript, performance, coroutine

My JS code takes a long time to run so it locks up the browser.

I could split it up with `setTimeout`, that would work. But then I need to restructure my code. It should be possible without restructuring the code (too much), I think, given a good library.

So, **any js lib that offers that**? Something like pseudo-coroutines?

I don't wanna use Web Workers for compatibility reasons.

**Edit:** I was asked what the lib would do. Well, consider this code.

```
dosomething();
for(var x=0; x<w; x++) {
    for(var y=0; y<h; y++) {
        dosomething2();
    }
}
dosomething3();
```

I could split it up with setInterval so I only do for example 10 iterations of the outer loop before returning control to the browser. But that would require restructuring the code a lot.  A lib could do some trickery to let me do it more easily. In the C# lang for example it's possible - actually in 2 ways - generators and the async keyword.

Comment: Are you going to show us your code? Maybe explain why it locks up the browser ('because it's running and slow' is *not* an explanation)? Tell us, at the *very least*, what it does? And what do you want this library *to do*?

Comment: On clicking a button, I fire up a long loop that does some number crunching - image processing. So, since that loop doesn't return for quite some time, the browser is left waiting for it and doesn't update the UI.

Comment: You can try using a callback function...

Comment: If you don't want to restructure your core too much (because is large/complex) then webworkers it the way to go. If you can't use it, then you should show us a snippet of your `dosomething2()` code; may be we can help you to make it run faster.

Comment: Just guessing: Is your "image processing" code iterating over the bytes of an image gotten through `getImageData()`?

Answer (score 2):

How about if you use a server side language to do the number crunching for you? You could send it the required data, and it would be processed asynchronously and returned to the client whenever it is ready.

This is a better approach than relying on the computing horsepower of the client for resource intensive calculations.

If you must make your JS loop asynchronous, here's how:

```
dosomething();

function iterate(count) {
    count--;
    if (count > 0) {
        dosomething2();
        setTimeout(
        function() {
            iterate(count);
        }, 10); // iterates every 10 ms
    }
}
iterate(10); //runs the loop 10 times, asynchronously

dosomething3();
```

Note that `dosomething` and `dosomething3` will fire near consecutively, while `dosomething2` iterations occur in the background. Each individual `dosomething2` locks up the interface, but since they aren't occurring consecutively, there isn't a problem.

Also note that while I'm currently throttling iterations to 1 every 10ms, you could set that to 0 and still achieve similar results.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/mW6vz/